# Optimization of transitive comparison (A>B, B>C => A>C)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, comparison, logical-operators

I've been stuck on this problem for almost a week now, and I think I need some help to solve it. I'm given a set of comparison in this format:

```
5  
2  
1 2
2 3
3 4
5 4
6 5
```

The first line denotes that there are 5 elements that can be compared (1-5)
The second line denotes how many comparison statement there will be  
Starting from the third line is the comparison statement. The first element is better than the second element. So in this case 1 > 2 , and 2 >3 and 3 > 4 and so on.

I'm supposed to output the number of elements that is better and worse than each element.
So no number is better than element 1 and there are 3 number worse than 1 (2,3,4). I think you get the idea. The output should be:

```
1: better: 0 worse: 3
2: better: 1 worse: 2
3: better: 2 worse: 1
4: better: 5 worse: 0
5: better: 1 worse: 1
6: better: 0 worse: 2
```

Here is my implementation for it so far

```
class Student{
public:
vector<int> better;
vector<int> worse;
};

void addComp(Student* student, int a, int b){

//push all worse elements into their better elements (there will be    duplicate)
student[a].worse.push_back(b);
vector<int>::iterator bIter = student[b].worse.begin();
vector<int>::iterator aIter = student[a].better.begin();

while (aIter != student[a].better.end())
{
    student[*aIter].worse.push_back(b);
    aIter++;
}

while (bIter != student[b].worse.end())
{
    student[a].worse.push_back(*bIter);

    aIter = student[a].better.begin();
    while (aIter != student[a].better.end())
    {
        student[*aIter].worse.push_back(*bIter);
        aIter++;
    }
    bIter++;
}

//push all better elements into their worse elements (there will be duplicate)
student[b].better.push_back(a);
bIter = student[b].worse.begin();
aIter = student[a].better.begin();

while (bIter != student[b].worse.end())
{
    student[*bIter].better.push_back(a);
    bIter++;
}

while (aIter != student[a].better.end())
{
    student[b].better.push_back(*aIter);

    bIter = student[b].worse.begin();
    while (bIter != student[b].worse.end())
    {
        student[*bIter].better.push_back(*aIter);
        bIter++;
    }
    aIter++;
 }
}

int main()
{
int studentCount, inputCount, testCase;
int a, b;
Student* student;

cin >> testCase;
while (testCase > 0)
{
    //The number of student that will be compared
    cin >> studentCount;

    student = new Student[studentCount + 1];

    //The number of comparison input
    cin >> inputCount;

    while (inputCount > 0)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        addComp(student, a, b);
        inputCount--;
    }

    //Start counting the number of better and worse student for each student
    for (int i = 1; i <= studentCount; i++)
    {
        //Remove duplicate from worse array
        sort(student[i].worse.begin(), student[i].worse.end());
        vector<int>::iterator last = std::unique(student[i].worse.begin(), student[i].worse.end());
        student[i].worse.erase(last, student[i].worse.end());

        //Remove duplicate from better array
        sort(student[i].better.begin(), student[i].better.end());
        vector<int>::iterator last2 = std::unique(student[i].better.begin(), student[i].better.end());
        student[i].better.erase(last2, student[i].better.end());

        cout << i " better: " << student[i].better.size() << " worse: " << student[i].worse.size() << endl;
    }
    delete [] student;
    testCase--;
 }
}
```

It works just fine, however it is not efficient enough for this problem. The number of element to be compared can be up up to 50 and the number of comparison statement can be up to 10000s comparison statement. And this is all for one test case only. There can be multiple test cases given. I would be very grateful if you could point me toward a much more efficient algorithm or help optimize my code.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to eliminate duplicated elements in addComp?
Moreover, you can sort them while addComp.

I would suggest you use set instead of vector since set could be unique.
step 1. replace vector with set
step 2. replace push_back with insert
step 3. remove the sort part

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
public:
set<int> better;
set<int> worse;
};

void addComp(Student* student, int a, int b){

//push all worse elements into their better elements (there will be    duplicate)
student[a].worse.insert(b);
set<int>::iterator bIter = student[b].worse.begin();
set<int>::iterator aIter = student[a].better.begin();

while (aIter != student[a].better.end())
{
    student[*aIter].worse.insert(b);
    aIter++;
}

while (bIter != student[b].worse.end())
{
    student[a].worse.insert(*bIter);

    aIter = student[a].better.begin();
    while (aIter != student[a].better.end())
    {
        student[*aIter].worse.insert(*bIter);
        aIter++;
    }
    bIter++;
}

//push all better elements into their worse elements (there will be duplicate)
student[b].better.insert(a);
bIter = student[b].worse.begin();
aIter = student[a].better.begin();

while (bIter != student[b].worse.end())
{
    student[*bIter].better.insert(a);
    bIter++;
}

while (aIter != student[a].better.end())
{
    student[b].better.insert(*aIter);

    bIter = student[b].worse.begin();
    while (bIter != student[b].worse.end())
    {
        student[*bIter].better.insert(*aIter);
        bIter++;
    }
    aIter++;
 }
}

int main()
{
int studentCount, inputCount, testCase;
int a, b;
Student* student;

cin >> testCase;
while (testCase > 0)
{
    //The number of student that will be compared
    cin >> studentCount;

    student = new Student[studentCount + 1];

    //The number of comparison input
    cin >> inputCount;

    while (inputCount > 0)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        addComp(student, a, b);
        inputCount--;
    }

    //Start counting the number of better and worse student for each student
    for (int i = 1; i <= studentCount; i++)
    {
        cout << i << " better: " << student[i].better.size() << " worse: " << student[i].worse.size() << endl;
    }
    delete [] student;
    testCase--;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I totally forgot about std::set. But it is still not fast enough apparently. I tested it on my machine and it runs 1000 test cases in 48s. I'm supposed to get it under 3. I guess I have to solve it from a completely different angle.